# PHP email body decoding

Tags: php, encoding, imap

after searching and trying solutions here for quite some time I couldn't find a fix for my problem, although it did fix one of the messages..

Anyways to the point, im currently using the imap function in PHP to get Gmail e-mails and so far it worked with 2 messages, but the other messages are still encoded or wrongly decoded and I can't  find where I did something wrong, my current code:

```
<?php

$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = '******@*******.com';
$password = '*******';


$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());


$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

$max = 5;
$i = 0;

if($emails) {

    $output = '';

    rsort($emails);

    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        if($i === $max) {
            break;
        }

        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number, 0);
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

        $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        if (isset($overview[0]->subject)) {
            $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        }else{
            $output.= '<span class="subject">No subject</span> ';
        }
        $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';

        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 2);

        if(isset($structure->parts) && is_array($structure->parts) && isset($structure->parts[1])) {
            $part = $structure->parts[1];
            if($part->encoding == 3) {
                $message = imap_base64($message);
            }else if($part->encoding == 1) {
                $message = imap_8bit($message);
            }else{
                $message = imap_qprint($message);
            }
        }

        $output.= '<div class="body">'.utf8_encode($message).'</div>';
        $i++;
    }

    echo $output;
} 

imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

Output:
http://www.mupload.nl/img/7pn51ldwpxj.png

Thanks alot upfront!

Comment: You've overlooked Content-Transfer-Encoding. Your two messages are base64-encoded.

Comment: No, those aren't.  Those are binary files.  The first one is a .gif file (see the GIF89a header).  The second is a zip file (PK header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've likely selected the wrong body part for those messages.  Those are binary files: one is a GIF file (see the GIF89 header), and the other is a ZIP file (see the PK header).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the Gmail PHP SDK for opening emails.
[PHP Gmail Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/)

You can't just base64 decode the body, because Gmail base64 needs to be "cleaned up".  If you just use base64_decode, you will find that the body is still full of weird characters.

```
$body_data = strtr($parts[0]["modelData"]["body"]["data"], '-_', '+/=');
$message_body = base64_decode($body_data);
```

I got this solution for base64 decoding from [Stackoverflow 'Mark as read mail method'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193429/cant-open-downloaded-attachments-from-gmail-api)