# Can't open downloaded attachments from Gmail API

Tags: php, email-attachments, gmail-api

I feel like I'm missing something stupid...

I'm using the PHP SDK for the new Gmail API to fetch an attachment from an email. I can get the attachment content, but unless it's a text file, I can't open the file after it's been saved. If the attachment is a PDF, it won't render. If it's an excel file, it won't open.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// this works; I get the attachment body, etc
$data = $g->gmail->users_messages_attachments->get($email_account, $email_message_id, $p->getBody()->getAttachmentId());

$fh = fopen(DOC_ROOT."/file.pdf", "w+");
fwrite($fh, base64_decode($data->data));
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 11):

There may be an issue with decoding the attachment data. Try using this string replace on the attachment data before writing it to a file.

```
  
    $data = $g->gmail->users_messages_attachments->get($email_account, $email_message_id, $p->getBody()->getAttachmentId());

    // Converting to standard RFC 4648 base64-encoding
    // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history
    $data = strtr($data, array('-' => '+', '_' => '/'));

    $fh = fopen(DOC_ROOT."/file.pdf", "w+");
    fwrite($fh, base64_decode($data->data));
    fclose($fh);
```

Comment: The data returned is returned using urlsafe base64 encoding, so you need to do the replacement shown in this answer.

Comment: What is the `p` on `$p->getBody()->getAttachmentId()` ? Do you have a link for the documentation for this function?

Comment: Great Answer, the String result returned from Gmail API -> getAttachment is urlSafe base64 encoded, so using the String replace we can have the string result base64 encoded then build the image.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, it should be `$data->data = strt($data->data,... )`

Answer (score 1):

You also need to join the path of where you want to store your file with the filename part of the message payload.

I'm not particularly well versed in php, but in python it would be the equivilent of:

```
path = ''.join([store_dir, part['filename']])
f = open(path, 'w')
f.write(file_data)
f.close()
```

Where the `file_data` is what you have decoded (your `$data`)

Comment: I can write to the file. But the file isn't a valid PDF/XLS/DOC/whatever file -- the encoding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to decode returned attachment data before writing it to file.

```
$attachment_data = urlsafe_b64decode(utf8_encode($data->data));
```

worked for me.